# NET8 Blazor can't find rendermode for a component

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0

I have created a `Razor Library` where I have all the UI parts and design. In this library created using **.NET 8** too, I have, for example, a component to change the theme to dark mode or vice-versa. I placed this component in another component called `TopNavBar` (the red arrow shows the switch from light to dark).

The switch invokes `JSInterop`

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<div class="darkLight-btn">
    <span class="icon @(IsDarkTheme ? "" : "active")" 
        id="light-icon" @onclick="OnLightClick">
        <i class="la la-sun"></i>
    </span>
    <span class="icon @(IsDarkTheme ? "active" : "")" 
        id="dark-icon" @onclick="OnDarkClick">
        <i class="la la-moon"></i>
    </span>
</div>

@code {
    /// <summary>
    /// Is the dark theme activate?
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter] public bool IsDarkTheme { get; set; } = false;

    protected async Task OnLightClick(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("switchToLight");
        IsDarkTheme = false;
    }

    protected async Task OnDarkClick(MouseEventArgs args)
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("switchToDark");
        IsDarkTheme = true;
    }
}
```

and the result in the page is

[image]

The *MainLayout.razor* is like that

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider

<div class="navbar-container">
    <div class="container">
        <TopNavBar Title="@Title" />

        @SearchContent
    </div>
</div>
```

In a Blazor project (with server and client) based on .NET 8, I added the library and in the `MainLayout.razor` I placed the `TopNavbar`.

First, the application takes a long time to respond to the user, maybe because it must read some JavaScript files. Second, the switch is not working, when I click nothing happens.

I tried to add to the `TopNavBar` a `rendermode` using what Visual Studio shows me (although it is wrong):

```
<TopNavBar Title="@Title" @rendermode="InteractiveAutoRenderMode" />
```

or the correct one (I think):

```
<TopNavBar Title="@Title" @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

but in both cases, I get this error:

> Error CS0103 The name 'InteractiveServer' does not exist in the current context

[image]

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwZdtLEtROA) and the guy said that I can add `@rendermode` to every component. What can I do?

Comment: https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/RenderMode/RenderMode.cs,bc305e96101a9727  They are a static property of a static class. So `RenderMode.InteractiveServerRenderMode` would work.

Answer (score 3):

In your `_Imports.razor` you need to add this namespace:

```
@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.RenderMode
```

Otherwise you have to specify inline the static class `RenderMode` where those static properties are defined as [Brian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625661/net8-blazor-cant-find-rendermode-for-a-component/77626637#comment136850120_77625661):

```
<TopNavBar Title="@Title" @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
```

Ps: It works because `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` is by default already in your `_Imports.razor`

From the documentation: [Apply a render mode to a component instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#apply-a-render-mode-to-a-component-instance)